# Prediction interval narrower than confidence interval when using metagen in R

Tags: r

I am conducting a meta-analysis with the estimates being presented as hazard ratios using the metagen function from the meta package in R. I was able to run the command but the prediction intervals generated is somehow wider than the 95% confidence intervals, which should not be the case? Have anyone encountered this issue before? If yes, how can it be solved?

I used the typical metagen command which is as follows:

```
ma <- metagen(TE = logee_hr,
              seTE = logse_hr,
              studlab = studylabel,
              data = df,
              sm = "HR",
              fixed = FALSE,
              random = TRUE,
              method.tau = "DL",
              hakn = TRUE,
              prediction = TRUE,
              title = "test")
summary(ma)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to be reproducible, ie provide the data in `df`? Your code doesnt really help much without the data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.